# Display long list of data from Web Service

Tags: asp.net, spinner

I am planning to develop an app where user will be able to see list of products sold in a unit and select them. Output will take them to a next page where users can see Vendors who are selling their selected product.

Since I am calling list( It can be upto 1000)  through Web Service asp.net, I am afraid it may slow down the system. Users can select multiple products at a time.

Please recommend what is the best way to achieve this.Can I use spinner like UI for multiple selection ? or some thing better

Comment: only call about 25 from webservice , then leave a link at the bottom "show more" then call 25 more , paging

Comment: Nice idea, how about the controls , is spinner fine? or which one do you suggest?

Comment: I just looked at an example of spinner , I think there are way better options for you, use gridview , just a table , put the results directly into html styled the way you want, ect.  It depends on how you want it displayed  - if there is a description of each item , maybe a picture , if it is actually just a list of name , then  maybe a UL list with each itm LI

Comment: if it is actually just a list of 1000 names , go ahead and load the 1000 names at once , that is no problem

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981084/virtual-listview-for-asp-net/10981815#10981815

Comment: App would be used by shoppers, and also product Vendors may vary on daily basis, so each time a shopper loads the list, a list of Available Products would be displayed. The list can vary 500-900-1000 each day

Comment: Take a look at this answer stackoverflow.com/questions/10981084/… – Aristos : Will it applicable to Android?

Answer (score 0):

For data paging and Gridview, you'll need to come up with a solution in code that tells your Gridview how many total rows you have so it will create the necessary paging controls in the header and/or footer.

I highly recommend using an AJAX solution like [DataTables.Net](http://www.datatables.net) with a web service. It has all you're looking for including unlimited virtual scrolling and paging. If you're using LINQ, then utilize the Skip and Take extensions to add the paging functionality in your code.