# appending the next set of rows with values on scroll od a div to a table dynamically

Tags: javascript, python, html, bottle

I have a page, which displays a table with 100 rows, upon scroll i want to add 100 more rows and continue the same for every scroll down. How to do it using AJAX and JS/JQuery? ( table data is displayed from MongoDB using python)

HTML template file:

```
%for doc in docs:
<tr>
<td >   
    {{doc["field1"]}}
</td>
<td>    
    {{doc["field2"]}}
</td>

<td>    
    {{doc["field3"]}}
</td>
%end
```

JS:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#divID").scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight)  
          {
            ** do something to get next set of rows here**
         }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573722/how-to-lazyload-a-standard-html-table-that-has-many-rows

Comment: You should look for the concept called ***lazy loading***. So better look for **lazy loading table rows jquery**

Answer (score 0):

Make an Ajax pagination API to get the data in certain range. This is how your request will look like.

```
http://yoururl.com/items?start=100&limit=100
```

You have to write code in Python to respond to such a request. Example: https://scalegrid.io/blog/fast-paging-with-mongodb/

Call Pagination API when you scroll down to the bottom of the table with right values. Append the result to your table.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://yoururl.com/items?start="+start+"&limit="+limit,
  success: function(data){
    $("#resultTable").append(generateHTML(data));
  }
});
```

You will have to set values of `start` and `limit` based on scroll history. Also write the generateHTML function to convert JSON array response to HTML.

Comment: Give him/her some reference on how to start!

Comment: I have told not to use pagination, instead I have to make page scroll @aadarshsg

Comment: @Anu I am not suggesting pagination but you need a way to send ranged data from database to the front end and Pagination API is a good choice as it takes in the range and responds with the data. Improved my answer to explain thins more. Thanks